# Compress Data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am looking to compress data in R for shiny App.My overall data is ~1.8 GB.
And the maximum limit for a free Shiny Apps Account is ~1GB.
I have 5 data sets and have tried the following methods (shown for only 1 dataset).The file if saved as a text file is 900MB.

Compression into CSV (compresses to a 574 MB file)

```
gz1 <- gzfile("geneExpressionMatrix_yf1.gz", "w")
write.csv(geneExpressionMatrix_yf1, gz1)
close(gz1)
```

Saving the data as RData.(compresses to a 340MB file)

```
save(tsneCoordinates_yf1, file="AgedMale_1_comp.RData", compress="xz")
```

Saving as a compressed text file (compresses to a 550MB file)

```
write.table(geneExpressionMatrix_yf1,gzfile("test.dat.gz"))
```

The maximum compression is obtained by saving as a RData,however this is still huge as I have 5 such datasets.
Is there any way I can compress RData further? or any other method to compress this data smaller than RData ?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: [related](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/brotli-benchmarks/)

Comment: If youv've got `character` variables, encode them as `factor`. If you've got integer variables, ensure that they are truly `integer` and not `numeric`. Maybe you can gain some space?

Comment: Also see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html and experiment with `pryr::object_size()`

Comment: You can also try `?saveRDS`

Comment: saveRDS also gives approximately the same size as Rdata

Comment: It seems hard to achieve the level of compression you need.  I don't know what sort of data you have.  If relevant, have you considered sampling?

Comment: do you really need to include all the raw data in the app?  can't you just let the user process their own data (which might be a copy of your data they got from somewhere outside Shiny) or include summary stats / fitted model / plots?